# Forms not getting submitted with MECHANIZE in PYTHON!

Tags: python, mechanize

```
from  mechanize import *
import cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

br = Browser()
br.open('http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/inquiry/inquiry-index.jsp')
br.select_form(name="main")
br.find_control(name="disclaimer").selected = True
reponse = br.submit()
print reponse.read()
```

The Above is my code. Now I expect it to show the HTML of this http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/inquiry/processDisclaimer.jis but it is not doing so instead returning the HTML of the same page. I do not get why?

Comment: Try using `mechanize` in the Python shell. It will allow you to experiment with what works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.items[0]`:

```
br.find_control(name="disclaimer").items[0].selected
```

A fuller code snippet looks like this:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/inquiry/inquiry-index.jsp')
br.select_form(name="main")
br.find_control(name="disclaimer").items[0].selected = True
reponse = br.submit()
print reponse.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're skipping some bits. I'm surprised it's not exploding.

```
reponse = br.submit()
print reponse.read()
```

should be:

```
br.submit() # returns nothing
print br.response().read()
```

Comment: Smae result! It is returning the HTML but of the same page not of the page which is returned when page is submitted in browser.